# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'deposits.Country' in 'where clause'

Tags: json, laravel, datatable

### I am fetching the data accurately in my views. but when i try to search in my datatables it gives me above error.. UNKNOWN COLUMN.. I am not getting this if its working one time then why it gives error on SEARCHING

```
$deposits2 = DB::connection('mysql')    
    ->table('deposits')
    ->join('users','users.id','=','deposits.user_id')
    ->select('deposits.*','users.Country')
    ->where('deposits.status','Approved');
```

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK5ij.png)

Here is the code from my views file

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {

    var table = $('#myTable2').DataTable( {
        processing: true,
                "serverSide": true,

        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{url('dashboard/adeposits/json')}}",
            "type": "GET"
        },
        "deferRender": true,

        "columns":
            [
                { "data" : "id", "title" : "Portfolio#", "searchable": true,

                    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                        var itemID = data;
                        return '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DDetailsModal" href="#" onclick="viewDetailsFunc('+row.id+')">D-'+itemID+'</a>';
                    }
                },
                { "data" : "unique_id", "title" : "UserID", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
                { "data" : "Country", "title" : "Country", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
```

Comment: post your datatable code probably the error is from your js

Comment: check now, i have posted my view file

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your datatable you can set field name in your columns.

```
{ "data" : "Country", name: "users.Country", "title" : "Country", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$deposits2 = DB::connection('mysql')    
                   ->table('deposits')
                   ->select('deposits.*','users.Country')
                   ->join('users','users.id','=','deposits.user_id')
                   ->where('deposits.status','Approved')
                   ->get();
```

Comment: @Mubixh Check your table deposites. Is it has column name 'country'?

Comment: i have solved it by giving "name" : "users.Country" in Country column in my view file..